# MIF/MID render in Xamarin.Forms/MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, gis, maui

Good afternoon, I'm working on a personal project in gis ingeo. I can export the map to MID/MIF format. Can I render this in somehow in Xamarin.Forms/MAUI?

Comment: if you're going to ask about some obscure technology, it's helpful to include some links so that we know what you're talking about

Comment: What you are describing is a "custom map", which is possible using Xamarin Forms Map component, but requires a fair amount of setup by you, writing custom code and using some third party tool to generate "map tiles". You may need to convert MID/MIF to a different format.  See [Creating custom Xamarin.Forms maps](https://aloisdeniel.github.io/xamarin-forms-custom-maps/) for one blogger's approach to this. Regretably, the github with their code seems to no longer be available. You might try contacting them at their new blog URL (mentioned at top of that page).

Comment: Actually, one of the githubs they mention is still available. See https://github.com/aloisdeniel/mapzen-tile-generator. You'll need to do something similar, to generate custom map tiles. (CAVEAT: I haven't looked at the details of what they did.) See also [OSM fie formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.